# Can't use high version of mediapipe on old python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, mediapipe

I am on conda venv with python version `3.6.13`, also on `mediapipe` version `0.8.3`, when running a python script (below) on a higher version of `mediapipe` version `0.8.11` and code crashes.

NOTE:
I tried to install `mediapipe` version `0.8.11` on conda venv but it fails.

CODE:

```py
import mediapipe as mp


mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles
mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands
```

ERROR:

```
 mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles
AttributeError: module 'mediapipe.python.solutions' has no attribute 'drawing_styles'
```

Comment: if you have error when you install then show this error in question (not in comments). If code crush then run it in console to get full error message and show it in question.

Comment: I showed the full error message above !

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. But I run `Python 3.9` without `conda`, `mediapipe 0.8.11`. Some modules may not work with older Pythons.